# C++ exception, thow const char* type and catch

Tags: c++, exception

I am coding using a very simple exception in C++.

but that is not working as i expect.

and i don't know why even though in debugging mode.

i attach a picture that show variable in eclipse debugging mode at the catch point.

i excepted that the code flow will go into `if` statement but it go into `else` statement.

as this problem is too simple, i think that i have misunderstood on handling exception, please fix my understanding.

```
throw "connection fail";
```

.

```
catch(const char* e){
    if(e == "connection fail"){
        clients.erase(client);
        continue;
    }else{
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
        assert(NULL);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: == compares pointers not the value of a string see may other questions+  don't throw const char* use some subclass of std::exception

Comment: Hint: How do you compare char buffers when given two pointers that point to the beginning of each buffer?

Comment: Protip: Throw something derived from `std::exception`, unless you like to annoy everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're lucky that the code didn't work as expected, there's a good chance it might have, and then broken when you rebuilt your code a long time from now.

```
if(e == "connection fail"){
```

The problem above is that you're comparing two pointers (that point to two distinct string literals), and not the strings themselves as you expect it to. The reason I said it might've worked is because compilers are allowed to pool string literals, meaning it would've used the same copy of the string literal in both places, and the check would've passed, leading you to believe that the code works correctly. Of course, there's no guarantee that that would always happen, and your code might break silently one day when you recompile.

To actually compare the strings, either use `strcmp`, or convert one of the operands to `std::string`.

```
try {
    throw "connection fail";

} catch( char const *e ) {
    if(std::string(e) == "connection fail") {
        std::cerr << "caught: " << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

A better solution is to throw types that derive from `std::exception` instead. I'd change your code to:

```
try {
    throw std::runtime_error("connection fail");

} catch( std::exception const& e ) {
    std::cerr << "caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `std::runtime_error` advice. even if lack of advice on how to perform cleanup.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf There's no code indicating what the OP is doing with `client` or `clients` that might have caused this exception. I could go on about RAII and such, but that involves having to come up with my own example of potential use case. If you want to write an answer that shows all that, you'll have my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't throw `const char*`, that makes no sense!

`throw std::runtime_error("My Error");`

`catch (const std::runtime_error& e)`

or create your own exception that contains variables which indicate exception detail, or different object types which indicate the problem! Then you don't need to do any string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare C-style strings with `==`, you must use `strcmp`. Most of the time.

The `==` is only comparing the *pointer addresses*. In this case you have two strings so they're at different addresses, even though they may contain the same characters in the string.

You can make the `==` comparison work if you can ensure that both strings are actually the same location in memory. Here's a way to make it work:

```
static const char * connection_fail = "connection fail";
throw connection_fail;

catch(const char* e){
    if(e == connection_fail){
        // ...
```

The better solution all around would be to not throw strings, but throw objects derived from `std::exception` instead. These contain a `what()` method that can be used to get a string describing the error.

Comment: "can't" and "must" are a bit too strong. in this specific context the advice is not unsound, though. still, imho it would be much better to address the Real Problem, namely how to retry or fail.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't think it's too strong - I don't think I've *ever* seen a case where `==` would give the desired result.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Surely some (or I would think most) compilers would properly handle `const char *str = "something"; ... if (str == "something")`. The latter would probably be in a function for it to make any sense, but I figured interning strings is common enough. I don't have evidence, though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @MarkRansom: apparently in this case the throwing and catching occurs in the same scope, whence a named pointer can be compared to itself very efficiently. regarding "must" use `strcmp`, that can have a quite high overhead compared to e.g. `memcmp` (I have no idea why). so, both the "can't" and the "must" are a bit too strong.

Comment: `==` _would_ give the desired result any time code needed to check for the same _instance_ of a string.  I think "you can't" is worded too strongly.

Comment: @DrewDormann my point was that I've never needed to check for the same *instance* of a string. Naturally there's an exception to almost every rule, but I haven't run across it yet.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf OK you got me, if they had used `static const char * connection_fail = "connection fail"` and thrown that, then they could have compared against the same pointer. I've edited that into the answer.